# PSR Autoloader function Failing

Tags: php, oop, psr-0

I think I may be missing something simple here and need a second pair of eyes. This fails with a fatal error class not found. The autoload function was taken from the PSR-0 github page.

```
<?php

function my_autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    return $fileName;
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoload');

new Vendor\Package\Example();
```

This is my index.php, the Class is located at Vendor/Package/Example.php, here is the contents.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Package;

class Example {

    public function __construct() {
        echo __CLASS__ . ' Created with Namespace ' . __NAMESPACE__;
    }

}
```

It works when I do this `require_once my_autoload('Vendor\Package\Example');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The autoload function was taken from the PSR-0 github page.

No, [on the page](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) there is no `return $fileName;` but `require $fileName;`